# Rails 5, simple_form_for, RSpec & Capybara - click_button does not work with my form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

The following Capybara/RSpec test is failing on my Rails app and I can't figure out why. I'm using the simple_form_for Gem to create the form and submit button. The update method seems to be working properly, as when I change

```
expect(@coin.currency_name).to eq('Updated Name')
```

to

```
expect(page).to have_text('Updated Name')
```

the test passes and the updated name is shown on the new page. However *@coin.currency_name* doesn't seem to be updated when I use the previously described expect method. When I manually update the Coin model (on the page, not using RSpec) it works fine and the *currency_name* is updated.

What am I doing wrong on this test?

**spec/features/coins/coin_spec**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Coins' do 
  before(:each) do 
    @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  end 

  context 'update coin' do
    scenario 'should succesfully edit name if user=admin' do
      @user.update(admin: true)
      login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
      @coin = Coin.create!(currency_name: "TestName", user_id: @user.id)
      visit edit_coin_path(@coin)
      fill_in 'Currency Name', with: 'Updated Name'
      click_button 'Submit'
      expect(@coin.currency_name).to eq('Updated Name') 
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/coins/edit.html.erb**

```
<div class='form-container'>
  <%= simple_form_for @coin, url: coin_path do |f| %>
    <h2>Edit Coin</h2>
    <div class="form-container__section">
      <%= f.input :currency_name, label: "Currency Name", class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.input :link_name, placeholder: "Link Name", label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
      ...
      <%= f.button :submit, value: "Submit", class: "btn primary-small", style: "margin-top: 20px;" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="form-container">
  ...
  <h2>Edit Coin</h2>
  <div class="form-container__section">     
    <div class="form-group string required coin_currency_name"><label class="control-label string required" for="coin_currency_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Currency Name</label><input class="form-control string required" type="text" value="OldName" name="coin[currency_name]" id="coin_currency_name"></div>
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default primary-small" style="margin-top: 20px;" data-disable-with="Update Coin">        
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After change of model, use `reload` method:

```
click_button 'Submit'
@coin.reload
expect(@coin.currency_name).to eq('Updated Name')
```

Comment: This is exactly why it’s not working for you (object is already loaded), not to mention there is no guarantee the update has happened when `click_button` returns, but you really shouldn’t be writing feature tests like this anyway. Feature tests should only be testing things the user can see/interact with.

Comment: Totally agree with @Thomas

Comment: OK I see.So what would be the correct terminology for this sort of test (where it's testing the functionality of updating objects)?